# Undefined control sequence when using \therefore

Tags: errors, symbols, packages

In my code I wrote :

```
 $\therefore$ There is a total of 21,168 ways that we can choose 2 chemists and 3 physicists.
```

However, I am getting the undefined control sequence error. I have used packages `amsfonts` and `amsmath`, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicated from an entirely different question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to load `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\therefore$

\end{document}
```

[image]